# SQL Server 2005 - query with case statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, cursor, reporting-services, temp-tables

Trying to put a single query together to be used eventually in a SQL Server 2005 report. I need to:

1. Pull in all distinct records for values in the "eventid" column for a time frame - this seems to work.
2. For each eventid referenced above, I need to search for all instances of the same eventid to see if there is another record with TaskName like 'review1%'. Again, this seems to work.
3. This is where things get complicated: For each record where TaskName is like review1, I need to see if another record exists with the same eventid and where TaskName='End'. Utimately, I need a count of how many records have TaskName like 'review1%', and then how many have TaskName like 'review1%' AND TaskName='End'. I would think this could be accomplished by setting a new value for each record, and for the eventid, if a record exists with TaskName='End', set to 1, and if not, set to 0.

The query below seems to accomplish item #1 above:

```
SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, TaskName, filepath
FROM (SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, filepath, TaskName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventid
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
AS seq
FROM eventrecords where ((TimeStamp >= '2010-4-1 00:00:00.000') 
and (TimeStamp <= '2010-4-21 00:00:00.000'))) AS T
WHERE seq = 1 order by eventid
```

And the query below seems to accomplish #2:

```
SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, TaskName, filepath
FROM (SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, filepath, TaskName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventid
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
AS seq
FROM eventrecords where ((TimeStamp >= '2010-4-1 00:00:00.000') 
and (TimeStamp <= '2010-4-21 00:00:00.000')) and TaskName like 'Review1%') AS T
WHERE seq = 1 order by eventid
```

This will bring back the eventid's that also have a TaskName='End':

```
SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, TaskName, filepath
FROM (SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, filepath, TaskName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventid
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
AS seq
FROM eventrecords where ((TimeStamp >= '2010-4-1 00:00:00.000') 
and (TimeStamp <= '2010-4-21 00:00:00.000')) and TaskName like 'Review1%') AS T
WHERE seq = 1 
and eventid in 
(Select eventid from 
eventrecords 
where TaskName = 'End')
order by eventid
```

So I've tried the following to TRY to accomplish #3:

```
SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, TaskName, filepath
FROM (SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, filepath, TaskName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventid
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC)
AS seq
FROM eventrecords where ((TimeStamp >= '2010-4-1 00:00:00.000') 
and (TimeStamp <= '2010-4-21 00:00:00.000')) and TaskName like 'Review1%') AS T
WHERE seq = 1 
and 
case
when (eventid in 
(Select eventid from 
eventrecords 
where TaskName = 'End') then 1 
else 0) as bit
end
order by eventid
```

When I try to run this, I get: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'." Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Haven't seen any examples anywhere quite like this.

I should mention that eventrecords has a primary key, but it doesn't seem to help anything when I include it, and I am not permitted to change the table. (ugh) I've received one suggestion to use a cursor and temporary table, but am not sure how badley that would bog down performance when the report is running. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to convert the result from IN to an integer. You can just do this:

```
and eventid in (
    Select eventid from 
    eventrecords
    where TaskName = 'End'
)
```

Comment: Mark, I'm trying to check if a TaskName with the same eventid exisits, and I want it to display a yes/no, true/false kind of value. If I leave the query like you have it, it will just bring back all eventid's that have a record with TaskName like 'Review1%' and another record with TaskName='End'. I'll need to get the total values of records with 'End' and those without End in my report.

Comment: @user329266: I'd like to help more but your question is rather hard to follow. I can help you more if you post a) all your table definitions b) some SQL statements that insert test data into these tables, e.g. 10 rows for each table c) the required output of the query when run on the test data

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another parenthesis after `'End')`, like `'End'))` and removing the parenthesis after the 0, as `else 0 as bit end`

Comment: Tried this. Now it throws the following: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you'll be able to this with a subquery surrounded by a CASE. The subquery checks if there are one (or more) records within the same period and with the same eventid that has a TaskName='End'. Then, if such row exists, the CASE clause returns 1 and if not 0.

```
SELECT eventid,
       TimeStamp,
       TaskName,
       filepath,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM eventrecords WHERE TaskName = 'End' and TimeStamp BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-21' and eventid = T.eventid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as TaskNameEndExists
FROM (SELECT eventid, TimeStamp, filepath, TaskName, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eventid ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS seq 
      FROM eventrecords where ((TimeStamp >= '2010-4-1 00:00:00.000') and (TimeStamp <= '2010-4-21 00:00:00.000')) and TaskName like 'Review1%') AS T 
WHERE seq = 1
order by eventid
```